# How to add log level to an NLog logging?

Tags: c#, nlog, log-level

In a recent project, I have loggings, looking like this:

```
2022-09-03 00:00:00.7450 | Debug | Company.Server.Communication.Connection.SendMS | Try to send Status
```

In an older project I've taken over, loggings look like this:

```
2023-06-05 14:33:01.3051 | Company.Server.OpenAccess.Manager | Configuring database manager
```

In other words,
the more recent style is `Date | Level | Class | free text`,
while:
the older style is `Date | Class | free text`.

In order to open the logger instance, the following line is used:

```
private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

I have no idea where the configuration of my logger is saved.

I would like to add the loglevel (`Info`, `Debug`, ...) to the logging, but I don't even know where the `Log.Debug()` command gets its configuration information from (which `NLog.xml`, is there an `NLog.config` or an `NLog` entry in the `*.csproj` files, ...).

How can I find the logging configuration and how do I need to modify it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are 2 ways to change your NLog configuration. Either [programmatically](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-from-code) or with a [configuration file](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file)

Comment: Did you look up [all the possible places for configs](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#file-locations) and checked them off one by one? What happens if you _add_ one? Is there a programmatic one?

Comment: @Roe: how can I know which way is used? I know there are different ways to do it. In top of this, I'm working in multiple directories (one for the main application, one for the DLLs, ...).

Comment: _" I'm working in multiple directories"_ - what does that mean? The _configuration_ still should be in _one_ place. Even if you define different targets for the main application and libraries (which is kind of odd, by ok...)

Comment: @Dominique to find this out you will have to first search for any code ressembling or containing code from the NLog library. If you don't find any search in your directory for NLog.text. This is all described in the examples I commented

Comment: @Fildor: I'm working with an application, loading a bunch of DLLs. The application is located in the main folder, while the DLLs are located in the "Modules" subfolder. Both directories have an `nlog.xml` file, and I don't know which one of those is used (or even possibly another file).

Comment: For your information: both `NLog.xml` files contain quite a lot of entries like the following `<code>${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}</code>`. As you see, the loglevel is included, so I believe these are not the entries which are taken into account.

Comment: I'm reading through the documentation and i don't see `level:uppercase=true` as valid value for level. You can set a `minlevel`, `maxlevel` and `level` where only 7 values are valid: `Trace`, `Debug`, `Info`, `Warn`, `Error`, `Fatal` and `off`. This is all documented inside this [page](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file)

Comment: _"Both directories have an nlog.xml file"_ - remove both and introduce one proper one. Also, enable [self-logging](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting#internal-logging) so you can see, where the config is pulled from and if it is valid.

Comment: There is a trouble-shooting guide, too: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Comment: @Fildor: I won't accept it as the final answer, but an answer, mentioning a trouble-shooting guide, deserves an upvote.